# WSS databases: are they needed for TFS to operate?

Tags: sharepoint, tfs, wss

Our server running Team Foundation Server 2013 ran out of storage space and I noticed there are 3 databases occupying 40GB: WSS_Config, WSS_AdminContent, WSS_Content.
As I saw these are related to Sharepoint which we never use. Is it safe to drop those and uninstall Sharepoint Foundation 2013?

Comment: They are sharepoint databases. If you are using Sharepoint with TFS or as a external tool without TFS server; then it's not nice to drop it

Comment: I don't even know what sharepoint is. And I bet the other developers never used that before either.

Comment: (: Sharepoint is a server product like TFS, and it can be used as a community portal & cms for TFS with basic integrations. It would be wise to consult to other owners of the server first before removing. But if you're sure, no problem occurs if you drop them. But it would be cool to remove SP relations from TFS admin console first, for the newly team projects you will create

Comment: [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd386329(v=vs.110).aspx) is an article for it

Comment: I would double check if _really_ none is using 40GB. If these DB were empty, they would be much smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the article. I decided to learn Git. No more tfs/sharepoint trouble...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are currently using SharePoint or it would not have 40gb of storage use. I would recommend that you increase the disk space on the server. Maybe you can move other things like your backup, drop folders, and such that often end up on the TFS server.